# overflow-x in css is not working properly

Tags: html, css

I have a website here and I just added a burger list for mobile users. When the burger list is closed the list stays outside of the screen. I don't want users to scroll to the side and see the closed menu.

[image: a screenshot from the website]

I've added `overflow-x: hidden;` to the `body` in css.

Just in case if you need to see it the code is below:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 70px;
        background-color: #3a345c;
        z-index: 99;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 40%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    /* More css but I don't think they are needed */
}
```

**PS :** I'm using django (i don't know if its important but I wanted to add it)

Comment: Please share a minimal example showing the problem you are facing on CodeSandbox(e.g.)

Comment: @hariom Its actually on the net right now, you can go to https://www.northernbladetl.com/chapter/0/ from a mobile device and see it for yourself

Comment: If the width of the page + nav is wider than the screen width, overflow-x on body would likely not work

Comment: @DonkeyKong I don't think its like that but could you check it just in case, the link is above

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display:none` when the burger is closed ?

Comment: When I do that I lose the animation when I open the burger

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.